# Use AutoMapper for mapping Nested Class Property along with Base Class

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I Map Nested Classes using AutoMapper in c#,

I am having Classes like..

```
public class Source{
public int Id {get;set;}
public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Dest{
public int Id {get;set;}
public AddressModel Address {get;set;}
}
```

How can I map `Source` And `Dest` class with Address and AddressModel Mapped
I am new to AutoMapper Please Help...

My Mapping Looks as below right now.

```
CreateMap<Source,Dest>().ForMember(dest=>dest.AddressModel,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Address)).ReverseMap();
```

Comment: You need to create a map from Address to AddressModel.

Answer (score 0):

Automapper automatically maps child properties if both source and destination have same name of the child properties i-e

```
public class Source
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddressModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ReverseMap();
```

UseCase

```
var source = new Source { Id = 1, Address = new Address { Name = "A" } };
var dest = _mapper.Map<Dest>(source);
```

Here you will get address object in **dest** variable